# Difference between IEC60309 2P + E and P + N + E

Tags: plug

From my understanding the 2P + E contain 1 wire for the line 1 wire for neutral and another line for ground. Then what's the difference between these 2 plug? Are they compatible with each other?

Comment: No, no neutral for 2P+E.

Comment: So the 2P + E use 2 phase electricity? Why would they need 2 poles for if not so?

Comment: Usually because some comity choose to build it that way. Google Norwegian three phase. They use 3P+PE and distribute 2P+PE to each “single phase” outlet. Requires twice the number of fuses but someone touching P will only get 1/sqrt(3) times the voltage to far less lethal.